# How to xkill an application by its id?

Tags: xorg, bash

I need to simulate the behavior of the keyboard shortcut (ALT+F4) using Terminal for a given application.

If I open for example **gedit** and click <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> , then GEDIT will be xkilled.
If I want to achieve same thing using Terminal, how should I proceed?

The following command (in order to kill gedit process) works fine:

```
kill $eval `pidof gedit`
```

yet, the command

```
xkill -id gedit
```

prompts me to click on the application client window in order to xkill it, thing That I want to avoid from the beginning.

The reason why I want to achieve this behavior is that some applications clients keep their process running, even though you ALT+F4 it.
My need is that I have an application that starts up on every login and I need to automatically close its client 3 or 5 seconds after it shows up.

Comment: Your question is not clear
do you mean to kill a process using terminal ?

Comment: Not really. I want to achieve the same behavior as ALT+F4

Comment: Xkill (or Alt+F4) will only terminate the connection of an application to the XServer. This may also kill the application but depending on the application it may also not. We should therefore not rely on `xkill` when we want to make sure an appliciation is terminated.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. I just want to separate the app from X server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equivalent of `xkill` is the `windowkill` function in `xdotool`. If you don't have `xdotool` installed, please run

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

With this tool you can indeed kill a window by using the search option and by specifying its class:

```
xdotool search --class gedit windowkill
```

You can find the pid of the process with `getwindowpid`, but just specifying the name of the class of window (i.e `--class gedit`) is enough. The tool is *non-interactive* in the sense that you do not need to click on a window to kill it as you sometimes need to do with `xkill`.

More information on the options available with `xdotool` are available with `man xdotool` and at the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xdotool.1.html). The manpages explain well how `xdotool` can be incorporated into a script much easier than `xkill` could be.

So I think probably `xdotool's` windowkill option is what you want and it may be more handy than that of `xkill`.

**However**, if you still want to use `xkill` and feed it the window's resource id, so that it closes the window without prompting you, you could parse the output of `xwininfo`, as in this example using the program `Meld`:

```
xkill -id $(xwininfo -name Meld | awk -F ':*"*' '{print $3}')
```

However, the name of the program sent to `xwininfo` must be in the proper case, so launch the program beforehand, and, in our example here, see if it is `Meld` or `meld`.

I prefer the `xdotool` command I gave above, as the case doesn't have to be correct: `Meld` or `meld` will work as the `search --name` switch instead uses regex to match a given string and ignores the case.

Comment: Thanks for this fine asnwer. That's exatcly what I wanted. I did not know xdotool existed and I do prefer it too :) However the xkill command you gave is going to be very handy.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `killall` which will send a TERMSIG (terminate signal) to the application you specify. you can use killall with the following command

```
killall <id>
```

for example, you can close firefox with

```
kilall firefox
```

if for some reason you must find the correct id of an application/process, you can always use  `ps`  to see all running processes and their names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yet, that's not what I am looking for. Killall will kill all processes related to a resource application.
Sure; i can grep a resource pid using: ps -A | grep gedit

Answer (score 1):

```
kill -9 <id>
```

will definitely kill everything associated with that pid.

to find the pid, I use

```
ps -u $USER -f | grep gedit
```

they can then be incorporated into one command if you need to do it often

Answer (score 0):

Use `top` Command to get  particular process Id. Note down it and type following command to kill Process.

```
kill <process id>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well, I know how to spot a process and kill it. That's not a problem. In my question I specified that I need to separate the running app from X Server using xkill command.